# Launch android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED through ADB

Tags: android, reboot

Is it possible to launch the action:
android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED

using ADB. Currently, I need to restart my device and wait until the OS broadcasts this message. Would be nice if I could do it without requiring a reboot.

Answer (score 2):

adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED

Comment: Executing this on Marshmallow reboots the device.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the package name before the class name (then you may write it without the package) like this:

```
./adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED -c android.intent.category.HOME -n net.fstab.checkit_android/.StartupReceiver
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not send that broadcast yourself (or a different one that will run your Receiver) just for dev purposes, and once you are done developing whatever feature you are working on, remove that call?